# How can I show a tooltip for each option on a dropdown with JavaScript or Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tooltip

How can I show a tooltip for each option on a dropdown with JavaScript or Ajax?

It is easy to show with the code behind, but this tooltip is not as fast as a tooltip created with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with help of javascript by adding this from code behind:

```
DropDown1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", 
                         "this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title");
```

OR

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1"
     onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title">
    <option value="1" title="asd">asd</option>
    <option value="2" title="zxc">zxc</option>
    <option value="3" title="qwe">qwe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if the tootltips are manual for different selected value of dropdown  then ?

Comment: then you just have to change the title of the option..like this `DropDownList1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("Title", "Hello");`..@user1545132

Comment: Yes..obviously, you can try and check..@user1545132

Answer (score 1):

```
use this  : 
<select name="ddlCity" id="ddlCity"
     onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title">
    <option value="Delhi" title="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option value="mumbai" title="mumbai">mumbai</option>
    <option value="Chennai" title="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="kolkata" title="mumbai">mumbai</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No good - the title won't show while the dropdown is dropped down.