# How to use a tooltip, or title, in a jquery dropdown checklist

Tags: jquery, html

I need to have a comment display when a user hovers over a jquery checkbox option in a drop down.

The title works fine right up to the point I add the dropdownchecklist.

```
<!-- Use a JQuery ThemeRoller theme, in this case 'smoothness' -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/smoothness-1.11.2/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css">

<!-- Include the basic JQuery support (core and ui) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DropDownCheckList support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.5-min.js"></script>  


<form method="post">
<select id="ps0" name="Role[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="a" title="Tooltip_1">1</option>
<option value="b" title="Tooltip_2">2</option>
</select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ps0").dropdownchecklist( {emptyText: 'Role(s)', width: 200} );
  });   
</script>
```

The check list the works but the tooltip doesn't. Does anyone know how to make them work together? An example file is here. http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/ddcl-sample.html

Comment: I assume `dropdownchecklist` is a 3rd party reference, or something, which is fine, just means I can't test it. What I recommend is you add an `onmouseover` event as specified here for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14208945/11700321

Comment: I added some CDNs, and a sample page link. The mouseover option doesn't work with the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this to copy the title from the select options over to the checkboxes after the plugin creates them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ps0").dropdownchecklist( {emptyText: 'Role(s)', width: 200} );

  $('#ps0 option').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#ddcl-ps0-ddw .ui-dropdownchecklist-dropcontainer input[type="checkbox"]').attr('title', title); 
  });
});
```

It would be more ideal to have the plugin just copy the title over when it creates the checkboxes so you don't have to put this code everywhere you use the plugin. However, it looks like that plugin hasn't had activity in quite a while, so you're probably not going to get a response if you ask the creator to change the plugin so it copies the title from the select options to the checkboxes as it creates them. So, you could just put the copy logic into reusable function.  Also, if you want to pull down the source and change it so that it puts the title on the checkboxes as it creates them you could do that.  That probably wouldn't be terrible since the plugin probably isn't going to get any more updates.

Comment: This looks like it should work but doesn't. Even after changing the ID from s1 to ps0.

Comment: The plugin puts an id on the ddcl-[id]-ddw element based on the id of your select list.  So if your select list has an id of `ps0`, then you need to use that same id in the selector for the options and the one that selects checkboxes to update the title attribute.  I updated the answer to reflect this using your example id of `ps0`.